# Make Devise check for column before signing in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm making a multi tenant app and want for devise to check if the user belongs to the current account before starting the session.

I already have a column called "account_id" in the User model.

So all I need to do know is to check if User.account_id = current_tenant.id

Can someone show me how to do that please?

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your question. Do you have another table called current_tenants?  Do you actually want to just render something different or only want the user to be able to access data if they are a tenant?

Comment: current_tenant = Account.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)

Comment: Each Account has one User, and each user belongs to Account. So I want the User to only be able to log in in its account.

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing your issue, but user authentication is usually a part of the user model.  Then from there, you can limit access of that user to different parts of your app including limiting access to only their accounts. The session already exists as soon as they come to your site.  If you want, you can set the account in the session hash upon login, but I'm do not know your full use case so it's difficult to help.  Sorry.

Comment: It's called authentication scoping

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, all you need to do is set `config.request_keys = [:subdomain]` in `initializers/devise.rb`.

Alternatively you can set it directly on the model if you are using multiple models and don't want this to be applied to all of them:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, request_keys: [:subdomain]
```

Then you can override `find_for_database_authentication` with something like:

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions)
  current_tenant = Account.find_by_subdomain(conditions[:subdomain])
  where(email: conditions[:email], account_id: current_tenant.id).first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on similar functionality, although have not been able to get it sorted yet.

---

In short, you're looking at [*authentication scoping*](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain).

This is, you're *scoping* the login around the `account_id` of the user:

- Login can only occur if `user` object is a dependent of a different object
- The different object (in your case) is `account`
- Thus, you firstly need to make sure you have access to `account_id` (through `subdomain`), then validate the `user` with a custom `Warden` strategy...

--

According to Devise' readme, you should be able to override the `find_for_authentication` method, but this only validates if a user exists with specific data... Maybe you could use it:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, request_keys: [:subdomain] #-> request key being a key from the "request" hash (request.subdomain)

   def self.find_for_authentication(warden_conditions)
      account = Account.find(warden_conditions[:subdomain]) #-> not sure
      where(email: warden_conditions[:email], account_id: account.id).first
   end

end
```

This would scope for the `account_id` but will not validate as to whether that account is valid.

For that, you'll need to use a custom `warden` strategy: [Good ref](http://climber2002.github.io/blog/2015/03/29/customize-devise-to-support-subdomain-authentication/)

I can update about what I'd do for the warden strat, but I've not got it working properly yet.